# Nesting dictionaries in python with a csv and I need to decrement or increment a date

Tags: python, loops, csv, dictionary

I'm excited because I got pretty far with some hints from a friend.  I'm trying to create a dictionary of dictionaries using a loop.  The csv I'm working with has dates from 2008-2014 and I'm using the dates as a key.  The csv looks like this:
year,title_field,value

```
2014,Total Housing Units,49109
2014,Vacant Housing Units,2814
2014,Occupied Housing Units,46295
2013,Total Housing Units,47888
2013,Vacant Housing Units,4215
2013,Occupied Housing Units,43673
2012,Total Housing Units,45121
2012,Vacant Housing Units,3013
2012,Occupied Housing Units,42108
2011,Total Housing Units,44917
2011,Vacant Housing Units,4213
2011,Occupied Housing Units,40704
2010,Total Housing Units,44642
2010,Vacant Housing Units,3635
2010,Occupied Housing Units,41007
2009,Total Housing Units,39499
2009,Vacant Housing Units,3583
2009,Occupied Housing Units,35916
2008,Total Housing Units,41194
2008,Vacant Housing Units,4483
2008,Occupied Housing Units,36711
```

Here's my code:

```
import csv

denton_housing = {}
filename = 'denton_housing.csv'
key = 2014

with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=','):
        while key not in denton_housing:
            denton_housing[key] = {}
            denton_housing[key][row['title_field']] = int(row['value'])
            key-1
```

When I print that, I get:

```
{2014: {'Total Housing Units': 49109}}
```

Which is awesome!  But I need this:

```
{2014: {'Total Housing Units': 49109}, {'Vacant Housing Units': 2814}, \    {'Occupied Housing Units': 46295}}
```

More importantly, I need it to loop back around and do the same for 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, and 2008, but stop there.

Comment: The data structure you've shown as your desired result isn't valid python. What you may want is a dictionary where the values are lists of dictionaries. That would look like {2014: [{'Total Housing Units': 49109}, {'Vacant Housing Units': 2814], 2015: [...]} Notice the extra square brackets. Small change, but a big difference!

Comment: Did you want a dict that maps 2014 to a tuple of three single-key dicts, as you seem to have shown, or a dict that maps 2014 to a dict with three keys, which would probbably be more useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to create a dictionary where each key is a year, storing a dictionary with the `Total Housing Units` and `Vacant Housing Units`:

```
import itertools
import csv
with open('filename.csv') as f:
   data = [[int(a), b, int(c)] for a, b, c in sorted(list(csv.reader(f))[1:], key=lambda x:int(x[0]))]

final_data = {a:dict(i[1:] for i in b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda x:x[0])}
```

Output:

```
{2008: {'Total Housing Units': 41194, 'Vacant Housing Units': 4483, 'Occupied Housing Units': 36711}, 2009: {'Total Housing Units': 39499, 'Vacant Housing Units': 3583, 'Occupied Housing Units': 35916}, 2010: {'Total Housing Units': 44642, 'Vacant Housing Units': 3635, 'Occupied Housing Units': 41007}, 2011: {'Total Housing Units': 44917, 'Vacant Housing Units': 4213, 'Occupied Housing Units': 40704}, 2012: {'Total Housing Units': 45121, 'Vacant Housing Units': 3013, 'Occupied Housing Units': 42108}, 2013: {'Total Housing Units': 47888, 'Vacant Housing Units': 4215, 'Occupied Housing Units': 43673}, 2014: {'Total Housing Units': 49109, 'Vacant Housing Units': 2814, 'Occupied Housing Units': 46295}}
```

Comment: I seem to get this when I bring the final_data:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'year'`

Comment: @ArchivistG you may have an additional column in your csv file. I tested this on exactly the data you posted with your question. Can you clarify how may columns your csv file has?

Comment: It only has 3, 'year', 'title_field', and 'value'

Comment: @ArchivistG Ah, I just realized that the file contains a header row. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: That was my fault.  I didn't include the header.  Ugh.  Sorry.

Comment: @ArchivistG No problem, glad to help!

Comment: Worked BEAUTIFULLY.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is that you don't want a `dict` in each value, you want a `list` of `dict`s. (Actually, if you want the exact output you specified, a `tuple`, but I assume you'll be happy with a `list`.)

So, instead of this:

```
denton_housing[key] = {}
```

… do this:

```
denton_housing[key] = []
```

And now, instead of setting

And instead of this:

```
denton_housing[key][row['title_field']] = int(row['value'])
```

… do this:

```
new_dict = {}
new_dict[row['title_field']] = int(row['value'])
denton_housing[key].append(new_dict)
```

Also, do that second part *always*, not just when `key not in`. (Also, you probably wanted `if` there, not `while`.)

You can simplify things from here, and build an even better data structure (you have three single-key dicts; wouldn't one dict with multiple keys be better?), and so on. But hopefully this will be easy for you to understand, so you get unstuck and can go wild from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
In[2]: import csv
  ...: from collections import defaultdict
  ...: 
  ...: denton_housing = defaultdict(dict)
  ...: filename = 'denton_housing.csv'
  ...: key = 2014
  ...: 
  ...: with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
  ...:     for row in csv.DictReader(f):
  ...:         denton_housing[row['year']].update({
  ...:             row['title_field']: int(row['value'])
  ...:         })
  ...: 
In[3]: import json
In[4]: print(json.dumps(denton_housing, indent=4))
{
    "2014": {
        "Total Housing Units": 49109,
        "Vacant Housing Units": 2814,
        "Occupied Housing Units": 46295
    },
    "2013": {
        "Total Housing Units": 47888,
        "Vacant Housing Units": 4215,
        "Occupied Housing Units": 43673
    },
    "2012": {
        "Total Housing Units": 45121,
        "Vacant Housing Units": 3013,
        "Occupied Housing Units": 42108
    },
    "2011": {
        "Total Housing Units": 44917,
        "Vacant Housing Units": 4213,
        "Occupied Housing Units": 40704
    },
    "2010": {
        "Total Housing Units": 44642,
        "Vacant Housing Units": 3635,
        "Occupied Housing Units": 41007
    },
    "2009": {
        "Total Housing Units": 39499,
        "Vacant Housing Units": 3583,
        "Occupied Housing Units": 35916
    },
    "2008": {
        "Total Housing Units": 41194,
        "Vacant Housing Units": 4483,
        "Occupied Housing Units": 36711
    }
}
```